# Managing user Presense 'onDisconnect' Firebase and Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have built authentication into my app using Firebase/Facebook Auth and now I would like to build into my app a system for **managing a user's presence** (eg; updating a 'status' field on Firebase for the user to say 'online or offline') as described in the [Firebase Docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

***My question is... where do I put all this managing presense code?**, here is my 'signIntoFirebase' function. would I create a separate function called 'manageUserPresense' and call it straight after 'firebaseLoginComplete'?

```
    func signIntoFirebase(firebaseLoginComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()){

    //Getting FB authentication
    guard let authenticationToken = AccessToken.current?.authenticationToken else { return }

    //Getting credential using authentication token
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: authenticationToken)

    //Signing in to Firebase using FB authentication token
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error { //if there is an error
            print (error)
            firebaseLoginComplete(false, error)
            return
        }

        firebaseLoginComplete(true, nil)
        self.isLoggedIn = true

        print ("Successfully authenticated into Firebase")
    }

}//end func
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the user is currently using the application?

Comment: Yes I do, I’ve currently created a separate function and call in my app delegate.